# Is there a reason that the binary byte sequence $2^{10n}$ and decimal byte sequence $10^{3n}$ are so closely related?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, binary

Computer storage is measured in decimal (base 10) or binary (base 2) notations of bytes.

[IMB Spectrum - Data Storage Values](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-archive-ee/1.2.4.0?topic=overview-data-storage-values)

##### Series

| Name | Symbol | Value (base-10) | Name | Symbol | Value (base-2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kilo | K | $10^{3}$ | kibi | Ki | $2^{10}$ |
| mega | M | $10^{6}$ | mebi | Mi | $2^{20}$ |
| giga | G | $10^{9}$ | gibi | Gi | $2^{30}$ |
| tera | T | $10^{12}$ | tebi | Ti | $2^{40}$ |
| peta | P | $10^{15}$ | pebi | Pi | $2^{50}$ |
| exa | E | $10^{18}$ | exbi | Ei | $2^{60}$ |

##### Value comparisons

| Decimal value | Binary value | Percentage difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 kilobytes (KB) | 97.65 kibibytes (KiB) | 2.35% |
| 100 megabytes (MB) | 95.36 mebibytes (MiB) | 4.64% |
| 100 gigabytes (GB) | 93.13 gibibytes (GiB) | 6.87% |
| 100 terabytes (TB) | 90.94 tebibytes (TiB) | 9.06% |
| 100 petabytes (PB) | 88.81 pebibytes (PiB) | 11.19% |
| 100 exabytes (EB) | 86.73 exbibytes (EiB) | 13.27% |

The values are surprisingly close for the exponents used. Maybe I'm lacking an intuitive foundation for exponents, but it seems coincidental that these two exponential sequences are so close. Is there a relationship here I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Because
$2^{10}=1024$
and
$10^3=1000$.

These are only $2.4\%$
apart.

This numeric coincidence
(for that is all it is)
has been taken advantage of
in the naming of values.

Comment: You probably mean $2.4\%$

Comment: Yup. Silly me. Upvoted.

Comment: Equivalently, $\log_{10} 2 \approx \frac{3}{10}$, a fact useful in, e.g., sound engineering.

Answer (score 1):

It's a coincidence, related to the fact that $\frac{\log 2}{\log 10} \approx 0.30103$ is really close to a rational number ($\frac{3}{10}$).

---

But out of curiosity, what if we didn't have a base-ten number system?  Which power of the base would be close to a power of two?  So, I did the math.  For each number base between 3 and 36 (except powers of 2, because those are obvious), I found the minimum power of two that's within 5% of a power of the base.  And here are the results:

$3^{12} \approx 2^{19}$; $5^{3} \approx 2^{7}$; $6^{12} \approx 2^{31}$; $7^{5} \approx 2^{14}$; $9^{6} \approx 2^{19}$; $10^{3} \approx 2^{10}$; $11^{11} \approx 2^{38}$; $12^{12} \approx 2^{43}$; $13^{10} \approx 2^{37}$; $14^{5} \approx 2^{19}$; $15^{10} \approx 2^{39}$; $17^{11} \approx 2^{45}$; $18^{6} \approx 2^{25}$; $19^{4} \approx 2^{17}$; $20^{3} \approx 2^{13}$; $21^{5} \approx 2^{22}$; $22^{11} \approx 2^{49}$; $23^{2} \approx 2^{9}$; $24^{12} \approx 2^{55}$; $25^{3} \approx 2^{14}$; $26^{10} \approx 2^{47}$; $27^{4} \approx 2^{19}$; $28^{5} \approx 2^{24}$; $29^{7} \approx 2^{34}$; $30^{10} \approx 2^{49}$; $31^{1} \approx 2^{5}$; $33^{1} \approx 2^{5}$; $34^{11} \approx 2^{56}$; $35^{8} \approx 2^{41}$; $36^{6} \approx 2^{31}$

Bases 5, 10, 23, 31, and 33 have a binary-power coincidence at a relatively small power of two (no higher than $2^{10} = 1024$).  This would allow terminology similar to “kilobyte” to be used early in the computer industry's development, when memory sizes were small.

- In Base 5, there would be a word for a 128 ($\approx 1000_5 = 125)$ byte unit.
- In Base 10, we have a word (“kilobyte”, or the pedantic “kibibyte”) for a 1024 ($\approx 1000$) byte unit.
- In Base 23, there would be a word for a 512 ($\approx 100_{23} = 529$) byte unit.
- In Base 31 or 33, there would be a word for a 32-byte unit, and for a $32^2 = 1024$ byte unit.

In other bases, the coincidence doesn't occur until a higher power of two.  For example, if we used dozenal (Base 12), we might have a word for $2^{43}$ bytes, but that's 8 *terabytes* (tebibytes), which is still larger than many hard drives today, so it probably wouldn't be a very practical unit.

There is one “out of range” binary power approximation I'd like to mention: $3^{12} \approx 2^{19}$, equivalent to $\log_2 \frac{3}{2} \approx \frac{7}{12}$, which is the mathematical basis of the standard [12-tone equal temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_equal_temperament) musical tuning, which approximates the “perfect fifth” frequency ratio of $\frac{3}{2} = 1.5$ as $2^{7/12} \approx 1.498307$.  Similarly, the familiar $10^{3} \approx 2^{10}$ (and its relatives $5^3 \approx 2^7$, $20^3 \approx 2^{13}$, and $25^3 \approx 2^{14}$) gives us $\log_2 \frac{5}{4} \approx \frac{1}{3}$, approximating a “major third” frequency ratio of $\frac{5}{4} = 1.25$ as $2^{1/3} \approx 1.259921$, or four semitones in the 12-tone equal temperament system.

Comment: Wow. That is pretty fascinating. Is there some relationship for the perfect fifth ratio that makes music work?

Comment: A short correction. "kibibyte" refers to the binary $2^{10}$ and "kilobyte" refers to the decimal base $10^3$. Unfortunately, vendor mislabellings and mistakes are frequent. Oftentimes, kibibytes are referred to as "kilobytes". These days, computer programmers are much more pedantic about this than they used to be, so "kibibyte" is acceptable.

Comment: @AuthorizedUser: It's generally believed that musical intervals sound most consonant when they have simple rational ratios of frequencies.  This includes the octave (2/1), perfect fifth (3/2), perfect fourth (4/3), major third (5/4), and minor third (6/5).  In "just intonation", the intervals actually use these ratios.  The problem with tuning an instrument this way is that you need to use two different ratios for a major second (whole step): 9/8 and 10/9.  Which means that sometimes, if you're using a different key that than the one you designed for, a perfect fifth is 40/27 instead of 3/2...

Comment: So, equal temperament sacrifices the purity of the ratios, narrowing the perfect fifth from $\frac{3}{2} = 1/5$ to $2^{7/12} \approx 1.498307$, for the sake of making *all* perfect fifths (7-semitone spans on a piano) the same ratio, thus making all 12 keys equally playable.  Check music.stackexchange.com if you want to further discuss the theory.